# Invert a bitwise left shift and OR assignment

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, or-operator

What would be the inverse function for this?

```
A = (B << 3) | 0x07;
```

How can I get a `B` when I already have the corresponding `A`?

Comment: So you're shifting left 3 and setting the low 3 bits to 1? What's wrong with `B=(A>>3)`? (assuming you realize that you lose bits when you shift)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't ever recover all the bits fully.

`B << 3` shifts 'B' three bits to the left, and it doesn't loop around. This means the state of the top three bits of B are erased - unless you know those, you wouldn't be able to recover B.

Example:

```
10101101 << 3

Turns: 10101101
          ^---^
Into:  01101000
       ^---^
```

The top three bits are lost, and the bottom three are filled with zeroes. Deleted data is deleted.

The `| 0x07` fills the bottom three bits (with `111`), so even if you didn't shift, you'd be erasing the lowest three bits with `111`, making those bits irrecoverable.

Now if it was XOR'd instead of OR'd, it'd be recoverable with another XOR:

`A ^ same-value` **can** be undone with another `A ^ same-value` because `((A ^ B) ^ B) == A`

`A | same-value` **cannot** be undone with another `A | same-value`

`A | same-value` also **cannot** be undone with an AND: `A & same-value`

But the shift still would cause problems, even if it was XOR'd (which it isn't).

Comment: Correct, you lose the top three bits. Even if the initial function was changed to be a left rotation, you will still lose information because the `| 0x07` is setting the right-most three bits anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Given (Using 8-bit `B` as example, using`0b` for binary form, demonstration only)

```
B = 0b00000000
B = 0b00100000
//...
B = 0b11100000
```

You can get the same `A`, so I don't think you can reverse the calculation, the leftmost 3 bits are lost.